# An error occured while communicating to the server when using jtable

Tags: c#

Hi everybody Please help me to solve it

default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="DemoJTable._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/themes/metroblue/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"        />

<!-- jTable style file -->
<link href="/Scripts/jtable/themes/metro/blue/jtable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jtablesite.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- A helper library for JSON serialization -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jtable/external/json2.js"></script>
<!-- Core jTable script file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.js"></script>
<!-- ASP.NET Web Forms extension for jTable -->
<script type="text/javascript"   src="/Scripts/jtable/extensions/jquery.jtable.aspnetpagemethods.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="jTable"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#jTable').jtable({
            title: 'The Student List',
            paging: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            sorting: true,
            defaultSorting: 'Name ASC',
            actions: {
                listAction: '_default.aspx/GetStudents'
                //createAction: '/PagingAndSorting.aspx/CreateStudent',
                //updateAction: '/PagingAndSorting.aspx/UpdateStudent',
                //deleteAction: '/PagingAndSorting.aspx/DeleteStudent'
            },
            fields: {
                Id: {
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                },
                Name: {
                    title: 'Name',
                    width: '23%'
                },
                Age: {
                    title: 'Age',
                    list: false
                },
                Email: {
                    title: 'Email',
                    list: false
                },
                Dept: {
                    title: 'Department',
                    list: false
                },
                CityId:{
                    title: 'City',
                    width: '12%',
                    list: false
                    //options: '/PagingAndSorting.aspx/GetCityOptions'
                }                    
            }
        });
        $('#jTable').jtable('load');
    });
</script>
```

default.cs

```
using DemoJTable.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace DemoJTable
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    public static DataTable Students()
    {
        string[] id = { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
        string[] name = { "Nguyen Van Cuong", "Ngo Thanh Nguyen", "Ngo Binh Tru", "Le Hoang Khoi" };
        string[] age = { "1983", "1986", "1979", "1985" };
        string[] email = { "nvc@yahoo.com", "nguyenngo@yahoo.com", "trungo@yahoo.com", "khoile@yahoo.com" };
        string[] dept = { "Developer", "Deverloper", "Leader developer", "Developer" };
        string[] cityId = { "1", "2", "3", "4" };

        DataTable tb = new DataTable();
        tb.Columns.Add("Id");
        tb.Columns.Add("Name");
        tb.Columns.Add("Age");
        tb.Columns.Add("Email");
        tb.Columns.Add("Dept");
        tb.Columns.Add("CityId");
        for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = tb.NewRow();
            row["Id"] = id[i];
            row["Name"] = name[i];
            row["Age"] = age[i];
            row["Email"] = email[i];
            row["Dept"] = dept[i];
            row["CityId"] = cityId[i];

            tb.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return tb;
    }

    public static DataTable Citys()
    {
        string[] cityId = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
        string[] cityName = { "Quan 1", "Quan 2", "Quan 3", "Quan 4", "Quan 5" };

        DataTable tb = new DataTable();
        tb.Columns.Add("CityId");
        tb.Columns.Add("CityName");
        for (int i = 0; i < cityId.Length; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = tb.NewRow();
            row["CityId"] = cityId[i];
            row["CityName"] = cityName[i];

            tb.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return tb;
    }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    //[WebMethod]
    public static object GetStudents(int jtStartIndex, int jtPageSize, string jtSorting)
    {
        List<Student> colStudent = new List<Student>();
        try
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in Students().Rows)
            {
                Student stu = new Student();
                stu.Id = row["Id"].ToString();
                stu.Name = row["Name"].ToString();
                stu.Age = row["Age"].ToString();
                stu.Email = row["Email"].ToString();
                stu.Dept = row["Dept"].ToString();
                stu.CityId = row["CityId"].ToString();
                colStudent.Add(stu);
            }

            return new { Result = "OK", Records = colStudent, TotalRecordCount = colStudent.Count };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message };
        }
    }
}
```

}

Student.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace DemoJTable.Model
{
    public class Student
    {
        [Required]
        public string Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Required]
        public string Name
        {
            get;
           set;
        }
        [Required]
        public string Age
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [Required]
        public string Email
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [Required]
        public string Dept
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [Required]
        public string CityId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

I am try to use jtable but I have error:An error occured while communicating to the server.

[image: image error]

These are my code in 3 files. I cannot find a error. Please help me to find error .

Thank everybody so much
Nguyen

Comment: That is an extremely vague error. Can you give us anything more specific to work with?

Comment: What do you need for more detail ?. I only create new project on VS 2013 and add these files to use jtable. But i don't know  how to fix this issue